# How to set correct xAxis time data in Highcharts?

Tags: jquery, highcharts

My Highcharts chart gets data with ajax. Java web-service generates data as
list of objects, where time field looks like `Jan 1, 1970 10:46:28 AM`.

After downloading this json data by ajax, the time looks like the int value `27988000`.

I want to properly show it on my x axis, so I need something like `10:46` values on my x axis.

My x axis description look like

```
xAxis: [{
    crosshair: true,
    type: 'datetime',
    dateTimeLabelFormats : {
        hour: '%b %e, %Y %H',
    }
}],
```

but, unfortunately, it shows incorrect time (`7:46:28` instead of `10:46:28`)
How can I solve this?

Comment: My initial reaction, as you stated its an exact number of hours behind what your expecting would be a localisation issue with date/time strings. See if anything in the following answer can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525538/convert-utc-date-time-to-local-date-time-using-javascript alternatively HighCharts has a universal UTC option which may be interfering http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33367397/highcharts-tooltip-wrong-date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Simon West mentioned, I only had to add the following:

```
 Highcharts.setOptions({
       global: {
            useUTC: false
       }
 });
```