# Javascript Highcharts spline chart with date values on X-axis click event returns incorrect date value

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, charts, highcharts

I have a spline chart which displays values (y-axis) and dates (x-axis).

The data for the chart is as follows:

```
{
  name: 'items',
  data: [
    [ 1476021600000, 200 ],
    ....
  ]
}
```

The date value that is sent to the chart is '1476021600000' which is Sun, 09 Oct 2016 14:00:00 GMT.

I have a click event on the chart to return the date value that is in the data javascript object.

What is returned on click is a different value '1476020807554' which is Sun, 09 Oct 2016 13:46:47.554 GMT.

The code for the chart is as follows:

```
$('#items-per-hour-chart').highcharts({
  chart: {
    type: 'spline',
    backgroundColor:'transparent',
    events: {
      click: function(event) {

        console.log(
          event.xAxis[0].value // returns incorrect value
        );

      }
    }
  },

  title: {
    text: 'Trending Words by Hour'
  },

  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
      month: '%e. %b',
      year: '%b'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Date'
    }
  },

  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Temperature'
    },
    labels: {
      formatter: function () {
        return this.value;
      }
    }
  },

  tooltip: {
    crosshairs: true,
    shared: true
  },

  plotOptions: {
    spline: {
      marker: {
        radius: 4,
        lineColor: '#666666',
        lineWidth: 1
      }
    }
  },

  series: items_per_hour_data

});
```

It seems to me that HighCharts is modifying the value and I can't seem to figure out how to retrieve the correct value (the exact value that I pass to the chart).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33367397/highcharts-tooltip-wrong-date

Comment: It does or it does not? On click you get the axis value in the place you clicked, not the point's x value

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. It does not fix the issue. It seems that I get a value close to the value that I passed to the chart.